# QGIS custom form : mixing Qt Widgets and QtQuick QML Widgets

Tags: qgis, pyqt5, forms

On QGIS 3.16 I am trying to create a custom form with some Python logic for feature navigation and a QML widget to display nicely images.

I embedded my QtQuick QML file in the custom form python file with this:

```py
def add_qml_widget_to_form():
    """Add QML widget in form."""
    global myDialog  # This is set in the main form function
    # manually drawn vertical layout in the corresponding .ui file
    vbox = myDialog.findChild(QVBoxLayout,"photo_layout")
    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    qml_url = "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\CustomForm.qml"
    path = QDir.fromNativeSeparators(qml_url)
    view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(path))
    if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
        for error in view.errors():
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage(error.description())
    else:
        container = QWidget.createWindowContainer(view, parent=myDialog)    
        container.show()
        vbox.addWidget(container)
```

The QML file uses a `Repeater` which fetches data from a table Relation:

```
 Repeater {
    model: expression.evaluate("relation_aggregate( 'test3','array_agg', coalesce(\"url\",'')||'ÿ'||coalesce(\"photo_type\",'')||'ÿ'||coalesce(\"orientation\",''))")
```

Unfortunately, the expression doesn't evaluate correctly (no output), and I guess it is missing the form scope with layer and feature information to work.
I would like my code to work the same as when I use the QML Widget in a drag-and-drop form which is feature-aware and evaluate correctly the expression.

Any ideas how I could deal with that ?

Another option would be to switch entirely:

- to QML, but I have seen little documentation on how to use PyQt functions to connect to signals for my navigation needs.
- to QtWidgets, but everyone seems so extatic on QML it doesn't seem the right direction.